# jQuery function to run once within a nested element

Tags: jquery

I have some HTML markup as example below - I want to use jQuery to move divA above divB where divB sits above divA - can someone help me achieve this - the code I thought would work, is adding new copies of divB above divA where it should not.

```
<div class="approachProcessBlockWrapper">
    <div class="divA">Content</div>
    <div class="divB">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="approachProcessBlockWrapper">
    <div class="divB">Content</div>
    <div class="divA">Content</div>
</div>
```

So after the jQuery function it should read:

```
<div class="approachProcessBlockWrapper">
    <div class="divA">Content</div>
    <div class="divB">Content</div>
</div>

<div class="approachProcessBlockWrapper">
    <div class="divA">Content</div>
    <div class="divB">Content</div>
</div>
```

So - the 2nd instance of "approachProcessBlockWrapper" div has divB moved above divA and no change to the 1st instance of "approachProcessBlockWrapper" where divA is already at the top and above divB.

Code I was using that doesnt work is below - can someone explain why this is not working?

```
function approachPageDIVSwapper () {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    if (windowWidth <= 1015) {
        
        $('.approachProcessBlockWrapper').each(function() {
        $(".divB").insertBefore(".divA");
        });
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() { approachPageDIVSwapper(); });
```

Comment: If it's just about reordering based on screen width, why not use css only for this?

Comment: can you move elements in the DOM via CSS?

Comment: Of course, with flexbox and order property. Or even with display grid. No need for slow jQuery here at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check inside `each` loop if the `first` div is `.divB` then get the reference of that div and use this to change position.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
function approachPageDIVSwapper() {
  var windowWidth = $(window).width();
  if (windowWidth <= 1015) {
    $('.approachProcessBlockWrapper').each(function() {
      //check if the first div under `approachProcessBlockWrapper` has divB
      if ($(this).find("div:first").hasClass("divB")) {
        var divs = $(this).find("div.divA"); //get refernce
        var other_divs =$(this).find("div.divB")
        $(divs).insertBefore(other_divs); //change position
      }
    });
  }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
  approachPageDIVSwapper();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="approachProcessBlockWrapper">
  <div class="divA">ContentA</div>
  <div class="divB">ContentB</div>
</div>

<div class="approachProcessBlockWrapper">
  <div class="divB">ContentB</div>
  <div class="divA">ContentA</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks - the theory works - as it does in your demo - but i cant make it work on my real life example... hmmm